# Apache error 403 after redirecting Apache to /media/... path

Tags: apache, ubuntu, media, http-status-code-403

When moving files from my main disk (where the OS is installed), to a second disk (other storage), I am trying to redirect Apache to the new disk, but this returns `error number 403`. I am running Ubuntu 16.04.

I originally redirected Apache to `/home/user/Documents` by adding the following lines to corresponding files:

in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /home/jawa/Documents/>
#<Directory /media/jawa/R2D2/Webpages>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

```
DocumentRoot /home/jawa/Documents
#DocumentRoot /media/jawa/R2D2/Webpages
```

This worked fine, but since I have moved the files to a new location, I must also redirect Apache.
When trying to redirect Apache to `/media/jawa/R2D2/Webpages`, I toggle the above comments and restart apache using `sudo service apache2 restart`. Visiting `localhost` in the browser returns `error 403` and using the command `cat /var/log/apache2/error.log` gives the following log:

```
[Wed Dec 27 17:24:48.583062 2017] [core:error] [pid 22343] (13)Permission denied: [client ::1:35704] AH00035: access to / denied (filesystem path '/media/jawa/R2D2') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path
```

Permissions and owners of both folders:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 jawa jawa 4096 dec 27 17:12 Documents
drwxrwxrwx 1 jawa jawa       0 dec 27 16:46 Webpages
```

What is causing the error and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Can you provide the output of the following 
ls -ld  /home/ /home/jawa /home/jawa/Documents
ls -ld  /media/ /media/jawa/ /media/jawa/R2D2 /media/jawa/R2D2/Webpages

Comment: `/media/jawa/`  permissions were wrong and `chmod 755`  solved the problem. Maybe you can explain, why `/media/` and everything else was set to 755 or higher permisions, but `/media/jawa/` wasn't. Don't reply to the comment, but write an official answer, so I can mark the question answered. Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we know one works and the other does not, list the permissions of both the folder structures :

```
 ls -ld /home/ /home/jawa /home/jawa/Documents 
 ls -ld /media/ /media/jawa/ /media/jawa/R2D2 /media/jawa/R2D2/Webpages
```

Once listed compare the two.
The default permissions are controlled by umask and this could result in the permissions being different.